# How do I return a Model from Entity Framework (Database First) that includes the Navigation Properties after the context is disposed?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

What I am asking is actually a little more broad than the question title...but that is kind of the specific question.

I am trying to thin out my controllers and move all business logic / interaction with Entity Framework into a Service Layer so that my controllers don't need the context at all, which I believe is the "right" way to do things.

The problem is that when I create a Service Layer method that returns a domain model, it does not contain the Navigation Properties and once I am calling this method in my controller and need to access these navigation properties, the context has already been disposed. This then forces me to make multiple calls out to other Service Layer methods to get the rest of the properties I need so that I can create my View Model.

I'm sure the issue is that I am not creating my methods in the proper way or missing some component of the correct architecture for this situation so here is some code to demonstrate what I am doing.

Service Layer method:

```
        public IEnumerable<Paper> GetPapersForReview(int userID, string courseID, string role)
        {
            using (USGEntities context = new USGEntities())
            {
                IEnumerable<Paper> models = (from a in context.Papers
                                             join b in context.Users_Roles on a.Paper_Types.Course_ID equals b.Course_ID
                                             where a.Status == "REV" && a.Deleted == false && b.User_ID == userID && b.Role.Name == role && b.Course_ID == courseID
                                             select a).ToList();

                return models;
            }
        }
```

Controller method:

```
        public JsonResult GetPapersForReview(string courseID)
        {
            int user_id = new User().GetUserIDByDomainAccount(User.Identity.Name);

            var vm = (from a in new PaperService().GetPapersForReview(user_id, courseID, "Reviewer")
                      select new PaperViewModel()
                      { 
                          Paper_ID = a.ID,
                          Proposal_ID = a.Proposal_ID,
                          Expected_Start_Date = a.Expected_Start_Date
                      }).Distinct().ToList();

            foreach (var paper in vm)
            {
                Proposal proposal = new ProposalService().GetProposal(paper.Proposal_ID);
                Paper_Types paper_type = new PaperTypeService().GetPaperTypeByPaper(paper.Paper_ID);
                paper.Paper_Type = paper_type.Description;
                paper.Resources = new PaperService().GetResourceList(paper.Paper_ID);
                paper.Proposal_Title = proposal.Title;
                paper.Author = new UserService().GetNameByUserID(proposal.Author_User_ID);
            }

            return Json(vm, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

So you can see after I make the call to the Service Layer method and get the properties that I have direct access to, I then have to loop back through that and make additional calls to get the rest of the properties that I need. I know this is not the right way to do things. So how do I structure things better to return everything I need from the Service Layer?

Some other related questions are: should I be returning IEnumerables or something else from the Service Layer and do I need to be calling ToList() in both places?

Comment: You have to use `Include` in the service method.

Comment: Use eager loading.

Comment: If I use eager loading and then pass that model back to my controller, how do I access the included models in the controller if I am not in my context? Do you still use the "." method like paper.Proposal.Title? If so is this not a feature of entity framework? The goal is to remove references to entity framework and the data context from my controllers  and only have it referenced in my service layer.

Answer (score 4):

You have the `.Include` extension:

```
public IEnumerable<Paper> GetPapersForReview(int userID, string courseID, string role)
{
    using (USGEntities context = new USGEntities())
    {
        var result = context.Papers
            .Include(paper => paper.User)
            .Where(paper => paper.Status == "REV" && paper.Deleted == false && paper.User_ID == userID && paper.User.Role.Name == role && paper.Course_ID == courseID)
            .ToList();
        return result;
    }
}
```

You can even use `.ThenInclude` if you have multiple levels:

```
.Include(p => p.Item)
    .ThenInclude(p => p.SubItem)
```

Comment: So if I use include and I am still returning the model type Paper, in my controller how will I access the included navigation properties without using a reference to the context? Does that "prefill" all of the fields of that Navigation Property? Hence eager loading instead of lazy loading as mentioned above?  Besides the obvious downside of potential lengthy database calls, are there other downsides to this method?

Comment: You can create a `ViewModel` for the returned data and pass it to the view. As for the ups and downs read the full documentation [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: In the Controller method that I showed above I am building a View Model from the service layer call...my question is though will I have access to the included navigation properties there in the controller without having to be in the data context? Because if I need the data context there then that sort of defeats the purpose of extracting Entity Framework from the controllers and only having it in the service layer.

Comment: The `.Include` method is best suited for the data layer because there you extract data from db. The viewmodel should be a set of properties mapped to the actual model (which already includes all the child elements). After retrieving the data you can create the viewmodel using the `.Select(p => new MyViewModel { // code here }).ToList()`. So to answer your question you don't need to use the `.Include` in the controller.

Comment: Ok but are you saying then that I should build the viewmodel in the service layer? That seems to go against the principles of separation of concerns as the viewmodels are tightly coupled to the views and the service layer methods should not know anything about the views. Doing it this way would also limit the service layer method for use in only one view potentially. Unless I am not understanding what you mean...

Comment: No. Use `ViewModels` for the views and `Models` for the service layers.